# Where do i find this code in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have been told to modify this code in wordpress back-end but I cannot find it anywhere by searching with notepad++. anyone know where it is?

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'price',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a custom query, it can be almost anywhere. You can search only this :

```
new WP_Query
```

this way you will find all the custom queries on your theme and you will be able to find this particular one.